# Send alert (mail) if a process (python code) takes more than specified time to execute

Tags: python, python-datetime

I need to send an alert (mail) if a process (python code) takes more than 5 minutes to execute, and also process should continue to run after sending alert !! I am using time.time() for timer, How can it be implemented ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know how to implement it using time.time(), but I suggest that you look at the [signal](http://docs.python.org/library/signal.html) module. First thing you need to do is to set up the handler via `signal.signal(signal.SIGALRM, your_signal_handler_function)`, and then schedule the SIGALARM to be sent to your process in 300 seconds via `signal.alarm(300)`.

This will work only on Unix, though.